# How would I wrap a javascript variable within a span or bold tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been given some JavaScript that creates a digital clock to go onto a webpage. This is working perfectly, however I'm trying amend it to wrap the am/pm suffix (or diem in this code) in span or bold tags so that I can style it differently to the rest of the time in the CSS.

I'm sure this would be really simple for someone that knows what they're doing but I'm really struggling. Any help would be appreciated, the JavaScript is below:

```
function renderTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var diem = "AM";
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
    setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    } else if (h > 12) { 
        h = h - 12;
        diem="PM";
    }

    if (m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    if (s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
    myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + " " + diem;
    myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + " " + diem;
    var diem = document.createElement('span');
}
renderTime();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

Use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) instead of innerText. That allows you to insert HTML tags into the string:

```
myClock.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + " <span>" + diem + "</span>;
```

Use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) and leave out the `diem` at the end of the innerText:

```
myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + " ";
var diemSpan = document.createElement('span');
diemSpan.innerText = diem;
myClock.appendChild(diemSpan);
```

Finally, you could put a `clockDisplay` and a `diem` span within your markup and access them appropriately:

**Markup:**

```
<div id="clockDisplay">
    <span id="clockDisplay-time"></span>
    <span id="clockDisplay-suffix"></span>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
document.getElementById("clockDisplay-time").innerText = h + ":" + m;
document.getElementById("clockDisplay-suffix").innerText = diem;
```

Comment: That's great thanks I used the within markup method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
var suffix = document.createElement('span');
suffix.innerText = diem;
myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + " ";
myClock.append(suffix);
```

Or, if you want to be more efficient (pure DOM manipulation):

```
var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
var suffix = document.createElement('span');
suffix.append(document.createTextNode(diem));
myClock.append(document.createTextNode(h + ":" + m + " "));
myClock.append(suffix);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/VSr6h/2/) a JSfiddle for you. It should work the way you wanted.

A solution is to create a different span for the time and your "diem", like this:

**HTML:**

```html
<p><span id="time"><!-- time will go here --></span><span id="diem"><!-- "diem" will go here --></span></p>
```

Then access them separately. You can style them differently too in CSS, like this:

**CSS:**

```css
span#diem {
    font-weight: bold;
    // your styles
}
```

**JS:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
    renderTime();
}

function renderTime() {
    // Insert time calculations here

    var time_span = document.getElementById('time');
    time_span.innerText = h + ":" + m;

    var diem_span = document.getElementById("diem");
    diem_span.innerText = " " + diem;    
}
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSr6h/2/) for the complete code in `renderTime()`.

Comment: I'd suggest only adding the code to the answer that's necessary for your answer to work. You can leave out 70% of that third code block. Also, the CSS is just eye candy. Personally, I wouldn't add it.

Comment: Noted for the future :) thanks. He specifically wanted to style the time and diem differently, so I thought it would be relevant to add the CSS for the answer to be more thorough.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the CSS bit in his question, my bad.