# Check if a string match the curret hour of time, then add an ID

Tags: javascript, time

I have a list of task starting with the clock and then the task description.

example `<li><span>11:00</span><p>task description</p><li>`

How do i use javascript to check if the string inside span match the current hour of time and then add an ID to the span if the hour (not minute, only hour) matches.

Comment: as simple as  $('.name1:contains("something")').addClass('name2');  But that does not have anything with date to do.. only adding a class if some string matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours).  In your logic, create a new Date, then use getHours() to check if it matches the hour in your span.

Comment: Thank you. getHours was what i thought in the first place. I guess the question i'm asking is how to make the content inside the span as a variable.

Comment: Well, without seeing more of the your code to see what's going on under the hood....I'd say use javascript innerHTML (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). You'd need to have an id tag on your span. The following SO answer Might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23759054/7104248

Comment: Sounds reasonable. thank you. I will try to figure out something and post it later.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something i can work on?

```
var time = document.getElementById('eventhour');
var hours = time.getHours();
function addtime() {
  document.getElementById("eventhour").addClass('newclass') ;
}
```