# Add styles to function-returned data

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add CSS styles to a string computed in Javascript. It goes through a series of transformation functions:

```
var fieldSetTransformation = setFieldTransformation(iteration);
fieldSetTransformation = stylePropertyName(fieldSetTransformation);
```

This value then is passed to a table generated in a directive through AngularJS's ng-repeat:

```
<tbody class="tableBody">
    <tr ng-repeat="line in linesArray">
        <td ng-repeat="column in ::columns" width="{{::column.width}}" ng-class="{
          'center-text' : (!line[column.key] || line[column.key].length === 0)
        }">{{line[column.key] !== undefined ? line[column.key] : '--'}}<span ng-if="column.key == 'user'">
                        <i id="plus-icon-styling"
                        class="fa fa-plus-circle action-icon">
                        </i>
                    </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I'm struggling to append it to an existing container.

**What I have tried so far?**

*Injecting the HTML directly into the returned value:*

```
var htmledField = [
  '<span class="propertyNameHighlight">' + fieldSetTransformation,
  '<span>'].join("\n");
];
```

No use, since this does not seem to be accepted anymore by current navigators (correct me if wrong) since it's a [security issue](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

The thrown result is just `<span class="propertyNameHighlight">000000</span>`
appearing in the table.

*Creating the element, then appending it in the view*

Also a no-go:

```
function stylePropertyName(data){
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.setAttribute('class', 'propertyNameHighlight');
  document.getElementsByClassName("tableBody").appendChild(newSpan);
  newSpan.innerHTML = data;
  return data;
}
```

This returns a null function exception.

I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758987/how-would-i-wrap-a-javascript-variable-within-a-span-or-bold-tag) question, which seemed the closest to my query, but in my case there is no clear container neither to wrap up the resulting string.

**TL;DR: What I'm trying to achieve?**

This green text over here:

[image]

That represents a cell. The data is not directly passed, it's generated dynamically through a series of functions and ng-repeats.

Any help or related disregarded question that I could get is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive?

Comment: Just did, and it worked, thanks @StanislavKvitash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by commenter [Stanislav Kvitash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4222181/stanislav-kvitash) (thanks!), I solved this by using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) :

```
<tbody class="tableBody">
    <tr ng-repeat="line in linesArray">
        <td ng-repeat="column in ::columns" width="{{::column.width}}" ng-class="{'center-text' : (!line[column.key] || line[column.key].length === 0)}">
            <span ng-bind-html="line[column.key] !== undefined ? line[column.key] : '--'"></span>
            <span ng-if="column.key == 'user'">
              <i id="plus-icon-styling"
               class="fa fa-plus-circle action-icon">
              </i>
           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Great it helped you!